# How do I make every span in my flexbox the same width while half of the items take a new line when there isn't enough space?

Tags: html, css

I have a flexbox that contains four spans with different lengths. I want those four spans to have the same width. When the width isn't enough to display all four spans I want to display two of the spans in one line and the other two on the next line.

```
    <div class="" style="display:flex">
        <span class="" style="display:flex; width: 100%;">
            <div>
                <span style="flex: 1 1 auto; width: 25%;">AliceAliceAlice</span>
                <span style="flex: 1 1 auto; width: 25%;">Bob</span>
            </div>
            <div style="flex-wrap: nowrap ;">
                <span style="flex: 1 1 auto; width: 25%;" >Carol</span>
                <span style="flex: 1 1 auto; width: 25%;" >DaveDave</span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Hey, is what you're looking for something like this? https://codepen.io/_cemsterr_/pen/MLLwXe
Or (looking at the pen) would the purple borders be spread out to 4 equal sized boxes?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible. CSS can't detect `overflow` so you will needs JS or a media query. Is the HTML fixed or can we change it?

Comment: BUT! - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MLLwNp

Comment: @Paulie_D : I'm okay with using JS or a media query.